# How to compare and later merge two multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I am trying to merge two multidimensional arrays in following way (example arrays are only examples, real ones are very long and have thousands of items):

$array_a:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:12
        [request] => 0
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:13
        [request] => 0
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:14
        [request] => 0
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:15
        [request] => 0
    )
```

$array_b:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:12
        [request] => 11
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:13
        [request] => 5
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:15
        [request] => 2
    )
```

Needed result:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:12
        [request] => 11
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:13
        [request] => 5
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:14
        [request] => 0
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2018-02-25 15:15
        [request] => 2
    )
```

Any? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you the result, however I don't know the logic that goes in the callback body.

```
$array_c = array_values(array_reduce(array_merge($a, $b), function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item['date']] = $item;
    return $carry;
}, []));
```

https://3v4l.org/fSVoj

What I'm doing is combining the arrays (they're all subset'd, so no inherent conflicts), then I go through and "reduce down" to an array key > value pairing, the key being the date/time, the value being the set. This gives the effect of coalescing each date/time to the same key in that array. The callback in this case simply "remembers" the last date/time block encountered, hence the "not sure what's needed" question.

Lastly, I get a version of the array with the date/times replaced with indexes (`array_values()`). This is also interesting, because sorting by date would be fairly easy if the `array_values()` call were moved to later.

This gives:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-25 15:12"
    ["request"]=>
    int(11)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-25 15:13"
    ["request"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-25 15:14"
    ["request"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(16) "2018-02-25 15:15"
    ["request"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Different things can be done, like only keep the first, or add each request (they're all zero in the first array). The mechanism should be the same though.

Comment: Interesting approach! +1 for no use of foreach and nice combination of array functions :)

Comment: This solution is still mystic for me but it works. And works even if new pair of key->value data is added to arrayA or arrayB , so this is why i am marking this answer as right one. But for the scenario i've wrote in question two upper solutions works also. So thanks to all.

Comment: @Sid Yes, it is actually [pretty easy](https://3v4l.org/OLh8Y) to parametize it into a function.

Answer (score 3):

One way to go:

```
foreach($a as $v) {
        $res[$v['date']] = $v['request'];
}

foreach($b as $v) {
        if(isset($res[$v['date']])) {
                if($v['request'] > $res[$v['date']])
                        $res[$v['date']] = $v['request'];
        } else {
                $res[$v['date']] == $v['request'];
        }
}

foreach($res as $k=>$v)
        $out[] = array("date" => $k, "request" => $v);
```

where `$a` and `$b` are your arrays and `$out` is the final result.

How it works:

Since we are comparing the dates and we know they are unique, we put them into a temporary array(in my case `$res`) as keys of the elements(keys of arrays are unique). For values of each element we compare the values of requests and store the bigger one.

So, the first `foreach` loop loops over the first array and adds elemenets to `$res` in the form of:

```
$res['2018-02-25 15:12'] = 0;
```

The second `foreach` loop loops over all elements of the second array, however, in here we also want to make sure we are using the bigger value for requests.

So this is, the `if` logic checks if the element exists, and if it does - gets the bigger value for requests and stores it to the date. If not - it does exactly what it did in the first `foreach` loop(creates new element).

Lastly, we want to put the array together to how it looked like, so we loop over `$res` and re-create the array as the original two looked like. The resulting `$out` holds what you requested.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to add values, you could use something like this :

```
$out = [];
// create new array using date as key, "object" as value.
foreach ($arr1 as $itm) {
    $out[$itm['date']] = $itm;
}
// foreach each element of the second array,
foreach ($arr2 as $itm) {
    // if it doesn't exists in the out array, simply add it
    if (!isset($out[$itm['date']])) $out[$itm['date']] = $itm ;
    // otherwise, add request to the first
    else $out[$itm['date']]['request'] += $itm['request'];
}
ksort($out); // Sort by date (Optional)
$out = array_values($out); // get values to remove dates from keys
print_r($out);
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-02-25 15:12
            [request] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-02-25 15:13
            [request] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-02-25 15:14
            [request] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2018-02-25 15:15
            [request] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: @Sid You're welcome :) Thank you too. @man0v solution takes the greater `request`, mine add them. Choose the answer that match with your needs :) Also, I use two foreach.

Comment: @Sid while it's true you use 2 foreach, you do sort the array. Also, it's arguable whether array_value loops internally or not.

Comment: @man0v array_values probably loops internally (I'm currently searching in PHP source code for that), but foreach made a copy of object on each iteration. However, it doesn't make such a difference unless you are hundred thousand of values in the array :)

Comment: @man0v Just for information : from _/php-7.2.2/ext/standard/array.c_ : _"Return just the values from the input array"_, loops internally on the memory pointers and returns references.

Comment: @Sid my point exactly. Was only 90% sure though, thanks for confirming. Nevertheless - your solution is exactly the same as mine(in terms of logic) - the difference is the style.

Comment: @man0v i think you wanted to mention Syscall , not me in above two comments :))

Comment: @Syscall my point exactly. Was only 90% sure though, thanks for confirming. Nevertheless - your solution is exactly the same as mine(in terms of logic) - the difference is the style.